# SSIS literal in servername

Tags: ssis, string-literals

I have a SSAS connection in my SSIS package that connects to a servername with the following syntax "servername\DEV"

Running this package I get the following errors:
Error: The string literal "servername\DEV"" contains an illegal escape sequence of "\D". The escape sequence is not supported in string literals in the expression evaluator. If a backslash is needed in the string, use a double backslash, "\".

What I have tried and found in other online sources is to put this servername as an expression and use the double backslash.

However this expression gets translated correctly to "servername\DEV" in my connection and the same problem occurs..

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
servername\\DEV
```

The backslash is the escape character so to do a literal backslash you have to escape it.

If you are feeding an expression from another expression and both levels require escaping try:

```
servername\\\\DEV
```

Comment: This is what I exactly have done and is also stated in the literature. However at runtime this gives the error I have posted: The string literal...

Comment: Are you going through two levels that requires escaping, have tried `servername\\\\DEV`?

Comment: No I just fill in the Servername\Dev in SSIS SSAS Connection and the connection works. However if I try to run it it execs but I get the error mentioned above. Running this package than from the sql agent results in a failure. If I modify to ServerName\\DEV (or with 4 backslashes) it will faill instantly inside Visual Studio.

Comment: How are you calling the package it in SQL agent?

Comment: SsisPACKAGESTOREDESTINATION; in VS it executes the processing task of the ssas connection. However in the logging it states an error. So the end result of this package is erroneous. Independent if run from sql agent or vs.